# Replacement of Skype4Com

Tags: c#, wpf, skype, skype4com

I'm trying to build a simple program (in C#) to send messages over Skype and tried to used Skype4Com. However, I found out, as here: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12384/how-does-my-3rd-party-application-work-with-skype-and-how-will-changes-to-skype-impact-my-3rd-party-application, that since the library has been discontinued it no longer works for sending a message. In trying to find an alternative for this, I've found a number of other SDKs which Skype offer - such as their Bot SDK, but they all offer far more abilities than I require.

What's the best SDK to use to produce a simple program to send messages over Skype?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This has now become a common problem, but luckily, there is a workaround that solves the problems being caused by the discontinuation of Skype's Desktop API.

```
Skype.Client.OpenMessageDialog(Skype username here, Message you want to send here);   
Skype.Client.Focus();     
Sendkeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

Note: The above will bring the Skype client into focus so it cannot be ran completely in the background, unfortunately.

You can see a demonstration here: [How To: Fix Skype4Com SendMessage Problem!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0zNxk8JMik)